# How to set the header font size using fancyhdr package?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, fancyhdr

Basically, I want the header fonts to use a different (smaller) font size than the size I set using `\documentclass`. What should be the option I'd be using ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headsep=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[L]{Personal Statement} % What other option should I use to get a custom font size ?
```

Comment: Have you simply tried `\fancyhead[L]{\small Personal Statement}`? Most likely you have already seen this, but see also: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Sizing_text

Comment: But I wanted a bit more "direct" control, so that I could explicitly set it to 10pt - is that not possible ?

Comment: @shan23: with `\footnotesize` it _is_ `10pt` when you have `12pt` as class option

Comment: the correct link to wikibooks is now: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like Werner writes :

`\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip}\selectfont` typesets whatever follows at size  with a baseline skip of  but I think `\small` is a better way because a lot of things are adjusted correctly, the definition of `\small` starts with :

```
\newcommand*\small{%   
\@setfontsize\small\@xpt\@xiipt
```

example :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headsep=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}     
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont Personal Statement}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you tell me which font size the header will be (10 or 12) ? It would be even better if you could give a short clarification as to why 2 arguments are needed for fontsize, and why \selectfont is used at all....

Comment: @shan23: `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip}\selectfont` typesets whatever follows at size `<size>` with a baseline skip of `<baselineskip>`. Are you familiar with the dimension `\baselineskip`?

Comment: A bit of searching revealed \baselineskip : \baselineskip is a length command which specifies the minimum space between the botton of two successive lines in a paragraph. Its value may be automatically reset by LaTeX, for example, by font changes in the text - but I couldn't really figure out how to calculate the changed value (is it set to 12 as the documentclass sets font size to 12) ?

Comment: @shan23 If you are not familiar with the dimension `\baselineskip`, I think it's preferable to use `\small` and I think it's always preferable to use `\small`.

Comment: @shan23: The font size and `\baselineskip` selection is interrelated since it leads to good typography. That's why *both* are required/selected using `\fontsize`. When using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, LaTeX executes `\fontsize{12}{14.5}\selectfont`, setting the font size to `12pt` and `\baselineskip` to `14.5pt` so that text lines don't overlay. To see the effect of different `\baselineskip` dimensions with different font sizes, use [`\usepackage{lmodern}`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm) and typeset some paragraphs using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum).

Comment: Thanks for the lucid explanation - you've convinced me that \small would indeed be a better option !

Answer (score 7):

I ran across this the other day:

```
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont Huge text
```

and have used it fairly extensively in my résumé.  I like it because it gave me much finer-grained control than the standard `\small` etc. commands.

You just place the package in the preamble as normal, then use the command wherever you want the font to be a non-standard size.  Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}\usepackage{fix-cm,soul}\frenchspacing
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}{\fontsize{20}{22}\selectfont Alfred E. Neuman}\\\end{center}
{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\textbf{\so{(111)222-3456}} \hfill {\fontsize{12}
{12}\selectfont 1313 Mockingbird Lane \\ {\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont \textbf
{email@email.com}} \hfill Boca Raton, Florida}
\end{document}
```

Sorry that my code is a bit messy.