# Can't put page numbering top center on some pages

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

Putting page numbering top center, some pages keep page numbering bottom center This happens only on the pages, that contain some kind of chapter/section/subsection header on top(I don't really know how properly name it). The issue is depicted on the following image:

[image: Issue image]

There's page numbering located at bottom center on the TOC page as well as on the introduction page. The same is when I start the chapter. However, when page doesn't contain chapter/section/subsection on the top, everything is fine. I've encountered this for the first time, being pretty new to latex, I have no idea what's wrong.

My preamble with all the packages and settings is messy, but seems the following code is exactly about page numbering and chapter/section/subsection modifications:

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}
\renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfil\thepage\hfil}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{16}{19}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{14}{17}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{14}{14}}

\titleformat{\chapter}%[display]
{\normalfont\chapfnt\bfseries\filcenter}{\thechapter}{24pt}{\chapfnt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, this is unfortunately not a full MWE which can be compiled as it is missing integral preamble information (e.g. `\documentclass{}` and other loaded packages). I notice however, that you only seem to modify the header of odd pages, which may be part of the problem. Furthermore, the start-pages of chapters by default use a different style, and this may have to be changed specifically in your case. In general, I would suggest using dedicated packages for all this, like `fancyhdr` or `scrlayer-scrpage` (especially if you are using a KOMA class).

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf, thank you for the reply! I was using ```fancyhdr``` but the numbers were too small and the issue hasn't been resolved. I added ```evenhead```, but the problem persists, though even pages has been modified even before adding this. Can you shred some light on how to modify start-pages of chapters/section/subsections? It seems to be the way to resolve my issue, though maybe not the laconic way.

Comment: Maybe try redefining the `plain` page style with fancyhdr: on the first page of a chapter, it is this page style which is applied, and it puts the page number centred in the footer.

Comment: If you have an issue with font sizes in `fancyhdr`, maybe check [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37879/how-to-set-the-header-font-size-using-fancyhdr-package)

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for the answer! Could you please elaborate on how to do this? I feel like this gonna help, but simply putting \pagestyle{plain} near e.g. TOC didn't help :(

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf yeah, this thread is really helpful, but the issue with different style on the start-pages of chapters persist and thus on such pages page numbering is still at bottom :(

Comment: Write in your peamble ``fancypagestyle{plain{\fancyhf {}fancyhead[R]{\thepage}` if you want all page numbers on the right side of all pages, or (recommended for two-sided printing)  `\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}`.

Comment: @Bernard, I find this pretty funny, but setting fancy stuff you've sent above, without ```oddhead``` re-declaring, makes page numbering on ordinary pages be at the bottom center, but page numbering on start-pages of chapters be located at the top center, so the problem transformed in upside-down version. Setting ```fancy``` with ```oddhead``` now makes all page numbers be located at the top center, but with different styles, but this can be modified!

Comment: I didn't notice that  you were using \@oddhead and the like. But  since you load `titlesec`, instead of reinventing the wheel, I would use the `pagestyles` option to load `titleps` and use `\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}}` for one-sided document and ``\renewpagestyle{plain}{`\sethead[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}}` for a two-sided.

Comment: @Bernard, hmm, interesting, could you provide code for ```titleps``` and ```pagestyles```, because just putting ```\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}}``` without anything else just throws error.

Comment: Or this part of code isn't part of preamble, is it?

Comment: It is indeed part of the preamble. Possible, you might have to add `\AtBeginDocument{\renewpagestyle{…}}`. What  is the error message?

Comment: @Bernard, error message was ```Undefined control sequence. \renewpagestyle```. ```\AtBeginDocument``` solved the issue, page numbering is at top right, but I guess ```\sethead``` controls this parameters. Thank you! Can you move your comments straight to the answer in order to mark it as a solution? Or can I modify my current answer and add ```\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}}``` option to it?

Comment: Hmm, setting page numbering to center via ```\AtBeginDocument{\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}}}``` became non-trivial for me. Ordinary pages, again, have page numbers at the center, but start-pages of chapter have not. Can you elaborate on way to fix it as well?

Comment: @PaulSnopov: Well, you should post a minimal complete code reproducing the  problem, so we can test. Just in case: try loading explicitly the `titleps` package, instead od via the `[pagestyles]` option of `titlesec`.

Comment: B.t.w., I don't know why I thought you wanted the page on the top right header. In this case, the command with titleps is simpler: `\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{\thepage}{}}`, whether one-sided or two-sided.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you a lot! This works really well and with ```titleps``` indeed there's no need in reinventing the wheel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of @ManuelWeinkauf and @Bernard, the issue has been resolved via adding this lines to preamble:

```
\newcommand{\changefont}{%
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[C]{\changefont\thepage} % except the center
}
```

With only `fancy` settings, the problem became "upside-down" version: ordinary pages had page numbers at the bottom while start-pages of chapters had page numbers at the top. Using both `fancy` and settings mentioned in the question, the problem has been solved!

UPD: Another way to solve the problem without reinventing the wheel is to add the next line to preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{\thepage}{}}}
```